# Objective-C MPMoviePlayerController iOS7 issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've seen this mentioned a few places around the web but have yet to find a concrete answer anywhere.

I'm trying to update an app so that it runs properly on iOS7. Part of that involves running a full-screen .mp4 video file (15.4mb / 40 Seconds long). Here is the code i use to setup the video, which runs fine in iOS6:

```
videoPlayer= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"introIpad"] ofType:@"mp4"]]];

videoPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
videoPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
videoPlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
[videoPlayer play];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoFinished) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayer];
```

As mentioned above this code ran perfectly on iOS6, however on iOS7 it now gives me the following error log:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
   kind = 1;
   new = 2;
   old = 0;
}
```

I've seen a few people saying that all they had to do is change the name of the video files so i've tried that with no luck. I also found some people mention the movieSourceType being a problem but i've tried to set it to "MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming" and that didn't work either.

Bit of a frustrating one and any help someone can give me would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you having this issue both on the device and Simulator? Or only on the Simulator? The Simulator in general will display sometimes weird/abnormal behaviour with MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to put that in my question, I'm only using the device.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to clarify since it might have been Simulator-related, but I guess not.

Comment: As you are using a local file for playback, setting the source type to streaming would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that this issue is a generic response when the device cannot play the video file.

I've tried with different encodings and multiple types of video without much luck.

However I've just tried a video with a different dimension and it plays, my original video file was 1536x2048 (iPad Retina resolution) and it doesn't like it. I've re-rendered the video out at 768x1024 (Half the original size) and it works perfectly.

It's not a very useful error log but i guess if you have the same problem as me then try as many different types of video and find the one that works.